# First two items in Kendo Panel

Tags: kendo-ui

I need to find first two  tags within Kendo PanelBar to add a css class. Can anyone suggest how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by tags? Headers? If this the case, you can use something like this code :

```
$(".k-panelbar li > .k-header:lt(2)").addClass("my-class");
```

Comment: I have few <Label></Label> inside my PanelBar and Need to add Class to First two Labels inside my PanelBar

Comment: Could you show your HTML code? But I suggest : `$(".k-panelbar label:lt(2)").addClass("my-class");`